# Gradle Clean Build and connectedAndroidTest

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric, build.gradle, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I'm playing with Gradle for Android recently... It's powerful but painful at the same time.

Initially, I followed Roboletric sample project, trying to make a gradle-based Android project with Robolectric testing support. After a while, I realise Robolectric doesn't even support API 19. Thus, I remove it from my build.gradle and try to use Junit and Instrumentation tests.

I'm not familiar with either Android or Gradle or Roboletric. I only know that before I removed Robolectirc, whenever I made a build `./gradlew clean build` I was able to run all the tests. But now, I have to call `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest` in addition to run tests while the `build` command only calls `check` but no test is run and thus always show SUCCESSFUL

I have attached my configuration here:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        packageName "com.example"
        testPackageName "com.example.tests"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        flavorDimensions "AppPackage", "AppEnvironment"

        appBasic {
            flavorDimension "AppPackage"
        }

        staging {
            flavorDimension "AppEnvironment"
        }
        production {
            flavorDimension "AppEnvironment"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        androidTest.setRoot('src/test')
        androidTestStaging.setRoot('src/testStaging')
        androidTestProduction.setRoot('src/testProduction')
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the `connectedAndroidTest` task don't run when you run the `build` task.

By default the `check` task run when you run the `build` task.

All you have to do is to add an explicit dependency to run the `connectedAndroidTest` task when the `check` task run :

```
check.dependsOn connectedAndroidTest
```

Comment: how should I add this as a setting in build.gradle?

Comment: @xialin just run in in Terminal panel in Android Studio: gradlew connectedAndroidTest